# How can I make a Python program terminate when the end of the input file is reached?

Tags: python, input, while-loop, raw-input

I am working on a programming assignment, and the directions specify:

"Your program should terminate when it reaches the end of the input file, or the end-of-file on stdin (when control-D is typed from the keyboard under Linux)."

This is what I have so far:

```
userInput = rawInput()
while userInput != "":
    #other stuff the program will do
```

This is my first time programming in python, and I am using pycharm editor. I am a little confused if this works. Normally in java I would check if userInput is null, but it seems like python doesnt have null objects? Also, does this account for the part in the instructions that says "when control-D is typed from the keyboard under Linux)."?

Since I'm using pyCharm to edit and run my file before turning it in, how do I test to simulate when control-D is typed from the keyboard under Linux" ?

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257158/python-handle-ctrld-with-import-signal

Comment: What is `rawInput()`? What does this function return when it reaches the end of a file?

Answer (score 0):

For performing operations till `EOF` , see my example code below. The outer `for` loop iterates till the last line, or you can say, the End-Of-File.

```
infile = open('input.txt','r')
lines = infile.readlines()

whitespace_count=0

for data in lines:
    #do your stuff here, for example here i'm counting whitespaces in input file
    for character in data:
        if character.isspace():
            whitespace_count +=1

print whitespace_count
```

And, when you need to do your work directly from STDIN, consider the following code below, here `sys.stdin` acts just like reading an input file. After you have entered enough input, tap CTRL+D till program exits

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    for data in line:
        for character in data:
            if character.isspace():
                whitespace_count +=1

print whitespace_count
```

Answer (score -1):

first terminating the program when it reaches end of file.

1. open the file using open()

   fp=open("sample.txt","r")
2. read the lines using for loop

   for l in fp:
3. print the lines

fp=open("sample.txt","r")

for l in fp:

```
print (l,end='')
```

if you are working with python2.7

fp=open("sample.txt","r")

for l in fp:

```
print l
```

Now we can use exception handling to terminate the input when crtl+D is pressed in stdin.here i am specifying the sample program

try:

```
str1=raw_input("Enter the String :")

print "Given String :",str1
```

except:

```
print "User typed ctrl+d"
```